# contentResolver can't allocate enough space to large number of files

Tags: android, database, cursor

Okay, so I'm building an Android music app. My test device has about 500+ songs.
I'm doing the following to import the music files to a List.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    count = cursor.getCount();
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    while(count > 0) {
                        String name= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                        String artist=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                        String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                        String albumId=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                        Cursor cursor1 = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
                                MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?",
                                new String[] {String.valueOf(albumId)},
                                null);
                        String image="";
                        if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
                            image = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
                            // do whatever you need to do
                        }

                        //arrayList_Title.add(data);
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("lsf", data);

                        musicName.add(name);
                        musicAdd.add(data);
                        musicArtist.add(artist);
                        musicImage.add(image);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        count--;
                    }
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            adapter=new ListViewPopulator(MainActivity.this,musicName,musicAdd,musicArtist,musicImage);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });

                }
                try {
                    cursor.close();
                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                    npe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }).start();
```

When I run my app I get the following error:

> android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window could
>   not be created from binder.

It occurs precisely on the line:

> Cursor cursor1 = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
>                                       new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
>                                       MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?",
>                                       new String[] {String.valueOf(albumId)},
>                                       null);

Am I interpreting this correctly? Is my application really unable to allocate memory to a large no. of files?
If so what options do I have?

=======

Comment: instead of `MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?"` just use `MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=" + albumId`, _ID column is not a string column so you cannot use  `?` in your `select` param and of course `close()` you `cursor1` when you are done with it

Comment: @pskink Not completely sure about that...I know for a fact that this same code worked for me a few weeks ago when I had less media files.

Comment: so dont close your cursors and wait for someone else answer

Comment: Lol, thanks anyways. :)

Comment: its not lol,  its a good practice to cleanup things when done

Comment: @pskink Sorry for being such a noob totally overlooked that `close()` your `cursor1` part.

Comment: @pskink That fixed it!